# Creating a directory in visual basic using range.text

Tags: vba

I wanted to make a new directory in Microsoft Word VB using a string from a paragraph, but it was the whole paragraph.  It must have included an end line character so a path name error happened, using Mid, I stripped the last character from the range.text.  Here's some code

```
Sub newDir()
    'Take the text in a paragraph selected by index and create a folder
    'MkDir ("C:\MainFolder\" & Mid(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text, 1, Len(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text) - 1))
End Sub
```

This way works.  Anyone know a better way to clean a string of such characters?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking more generally, you need to perform cleanup and remove not allowed chars from string which is going to be folder name. Once I faced the same trouble in the similar situation - save hundreds of emails from Outlook using Subjects as names. Below are 2 approaches, both use **RegEx**:

- Create the list of unacceptable chars using the following pattern:

  ```
  RegX_NAChars.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
  ```

`Chr(34)` is double quote, for obvious reasons it's impossible to list it directly. For your particular case you should add to the list so called "new line" chars as well using `"[start of pattern]" & "\" & Chr(10) & "\" & Chr(13) & "[rest of pattern]"`. The order of chars in pattern does not matter.

- The opposite approach is declare the list of allowed chars and remove all the rest:

  ```
  RegX_NAChars.Pattern = "[^\w \-.]"
  ```

The above pattern means all **BUT** latin letters, digits, space, dot and hyphen will be replaced / removed.

Both approaches have their own pros and cons, but but I think main reasons are:

1. **Disallowed chars** should be used when the goal is to preserve original string as much as possible.
2. **Allowed chars** list should be used when the name is not so important, but saving any file with no errors is the #1 goal.

This is the relevant piece of code for RegEx use:

```
    Dim RegX_NAChars As Object

    Set RegX_NAChars = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegX_NAChars.Pattern = [**use any of the above**]
    RegX_NAChars.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX_NAChars.Global = True
    ........[**your code**]........
    RegX_NAChars.Replace(String_to_Cleanup, "")
```

`RegX_NAChars.Replace` above will replace all matching chars with the defined replacement string. In my case it's `""` - empty string, which means chars are thrown away. Replace it to anything (of course, these MUST be allowed for folder name chars as well - e.g. use `_`).

Read more about RegEx: http://www.jose.it-berater.org/scripting/regexp/regular_expression_syntax.htm

Comment: In addition to the Regex link above, here is another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/2521004) with a few examples specific to Excel.